# Java: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not executing

Tags: java, mysql

So I'm looking to find a way to import data from a .txt file into my mysql table using a java desktop application, I wrote these lines of code but when I run my program I can see the Jform and the first button work properly, but when I press the second one, nothing happens. What should I change?

```
  private void ouvrirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();
            filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
            chemin.setText(filename);
        }                                      

    private void chargerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        


               String tablename = "tmp";

            try{

            stm=maConnexion.ObtenirConnexion().createStatement();
            stm.executeUpdate("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"" + filename + "\" INTO TABLE " + tablename);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fichier trace chargé avec succés");

        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);

        }
```

Comment: *"What should I change?"* - This Question!  1) Make your problem description clearer: what buttons? what are they supposed to do? how do they relate to the code you showed us? 2) Include the stacktrace.  For example, change your code to print out the SQLException stacktrace.

Comment: @AlaeddineHedhly is your table name `tmp` is created in mysql db?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For clarifying your situation, you can run the command in your mysql console. If succeeds, then you can try it in your code.

First try,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/foo.txt' 
INTO TABLE tmp;
```

Second try,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/foo.txt' 
INTO TABLE tmp COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

Third try,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/foo.txt' INTO TABLE tmp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Forth try,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
    INFILE '/tmp/mydata.txt' INTO TABLE tmp
    COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t'  ## This should be your delimiter
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'; ## ...and if text is enclosed, specify here
```

From those, which runs perfectly, you can implement your code.

For more,
You can go through [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loading-tables.html)

### Resource Link:

[LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)